# React Native Error __DEV__ === true / blank white screen Xcode simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I have gone through a bunch of answers on github and stack overflow with no luck. I am getting the following error only in the chrome debug console.

> *Running application [app name] with appParams: {"rootTag":1,"initialProps":{}}. **DEV** === true, development-level
>   warning are ON, performance optimizations are OFF*

In addition, I now see a blank white screen in the Xcode Simulator.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Getting the same thing in React Native .42